# Making Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to make a dictionary on Python inserting a list and values in with a loop?

Say I have two lists that looks like so

```
for i in holders:
    print(i)
```

gives...

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 1]
[4, 2]
[4, 3]
[4, 4]
[5, 1]
[5, 2]
[5, 3]
[5, 4]
```

and the other one

```
for row in myArray:
    print(row)

['0.0', '0.0', 'NaN']
['1.0', '0.0', '1.0']
['2.0', '0.0', 'NaN']
['3.0', '0.0', 'NaN']
['0.0', '1.0', '2.0']
['1.0', '1.0', '3.0']
['2.0', '1.0', '4.0']
['3.0', '1.0', 'NaN']
['0.0', '2.0', '5.0']
['1.0', '2.0', '6.0']
['2.0', '2.0', '7.0']
['3.0', '2.0', 'NaN']
['0.0', '3.0', 'NaN']
['1.0', '3.0', 'NaN']
['2.0', '3.0', '8.0']
['3.0', '3.0', '9.0']
['0.0', '4.0', 'NaN']
['1.0', '4.0', 'NaN']
['2.0', '4.0', 'NaN']
['3.0', '4.0', '10.0']
```

I want to write a Dictionary in python that looks like this

```
Diction = 
    { '[1,1]': '-1'
      '[1,2]': '1'
```

... and so on 
i want to write -1 if the 3rd number of a line is NaN
if it is a real number than i would write that number..

is this making sense?
I spent hours think and trying and no luck

Comment: Where is your code? What is the closest you got, what exactly is wrong with it and how do you think it could be improved? Did it give you errors (provide the full traceback) or unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Of course it's possible, but this isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
my_dict = {str(h):l[-1] if l[-1] is not 'NaN' else '-1' for h, l in zip(holders, myArray)}
```

Also, you should avoid identifiers like `myArray` -- camelCase is [considered bad Python style](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

This will give you an extra space inside the stringified list used as a key, but I suspect that that's not worth taking out (i.e. if you plan to check the key against other stringified lists, it's going to create more work for you).

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[1, 1],[1, 2],[1, 3]]

l2= [['0.0', '0.0', 'NaN'],['1.0', '0.0', '1.0'],['2.0', '0.0', 'NaN'],['3.0', '0.0', 'NaN']]

d = {}
for k,v in zip(l,l2):
    if v[-1] == "NaN":
       d[str(k)] = '-1'
    else:
        d[str(k)] = v[-1]

{'[1, 2]': '1.0', '[1, 1]': '-1', '[1, 3]': '-1'}
```